# Import CSS files into VSCode Custom Extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

**Hey Guys,**

I've already created a custom theme extension for vscode.

Is it possible to add/import/inject/whatever `CSS` files into my extension?

Comment: ... yes?⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀

Comment: No, a theme does just describe colors to use, they are transformed to a CSS and injected in the editor, if you create a webview you can use any CSS you want see the doc page

Comment: @rioV8 my bad. my brain focused on the title and somehow completely ignored the theme context. I thought the question was something about webviews or something.

Comment: thanks @rioV8, i'm new in making vscode extensions. could you tell me how to use webviews?

Comment: read https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/webview and https://code.visualstudio.com/api/ux-guidelines/webviews

Comment: if you read the Get Started pages for extensions, how likely is it that in their neighborhood you can find a link for WebViews and WebviewViews

Comment: thank you guys, but i want to override some core style css classes and ids via injecting, if it is possible ...  any other idea except WebView?